# Помогите с кодом AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute '_Player__lvl'. Did you mean: '_Player__LVL'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xcode, pycharm

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

class Player:

    __LVL, __HEALTH = 1, 100
    __slots__ = ['__lvl', '__health', '__born']

    def __int__(self):
        self.__lvl = Player.__LVL
        self.__health = Player.__HEALTH
        self.__born = dt.now()

    def get_lvl(self):
        return self.__lvl

    def set_lvl(self, numeric):
        self.__lvl += numeric

x = Player()
print(x.get_lvl())
```

Ошибка:

AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute '_Player__lvl'. Did you mean: '_Player__LVL'?

Comment: не `__int__`, a `__init__` :)

Comment: Спасибо вам большое